# IOS Swift how can stop re-creating cells on drag or scroling in tableview

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, xcode6

I am Creating a tableview using custom cell with textfield. When i enter text in tableviewcell textfield and when i scroll the tableview the data is changing . Means re painting cells . How can i stop reloading cell on drag or scroll in IOS 8 swift 
Thanks

Comment: This is the intended behaviour, in order to optimize the cpu/memory pressure of scrolling large lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your want your cell not re-used, try to make it a subclass of UITableViewCell with a unique identifier, and do not use the identifier with other cells. I haven't test it yet, just hope it will solve your problem.

Ps. If the textfield's text is still overwritten, make a check at the cell's class file (like making an if-else statement checking if the textfield's text is empty).

Detailed workflow:
In **cellForRowAtIndexPath()**, after you dequeue the cell, normally you will set some property of your custom cell to refresh the data it holds. To implement this, you need to add a **didSet** observer on the property at the cell's class file. To achieve the goal you want, you can also add the checking code in the **didSet** observer.

Comment: Sorry I not Understood how can i do that?

Comment: @damodarpatel You mean the second part? I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Your case. You need to customize your keyboard.
Add [Prev][Next] buttons on top of the keyboard and avoid scrolling.

Basically this idea is useful in form based app. May be your doing that kind.

And yes, Stop relaoding of cells is not good to app. If you will implement this. Apple will not approve your app. So avoid this kind of stuffs.

Answer (score 0):

This is how cells work in a UITableView. The standard implementation of the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method dequeues cells and reuses them.

And ideally your app should save the text from the text fields and change the correct text in the cells depending on their indexPath in the same method's implementation.

If you do not want to do that, a **dirty** workaround would be to create a new cell every time in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method instead of dequeuing rows.*

*Do not do this unless absolutely necessary. This is very bad coding practice